# Incorrectly installed ADT plugin on eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I recently installed ADT plugin on eclipse juno with jre7. After restarting eclipse, I never saw the expected "Welcome to Android Development" window. In eclipse installed software tab, I see Android DDMS, Android Development Tools, Android Heirarchy Viewer, Android Traceview, Tracer for OpenGL ES all with version 22.2.1.v201209180102-833290. However, in my Configuration error log, I see

```
  !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2013-10-12 07:23:56.828
  !MESSAGE Invalid preference category path: com.android.ide.eclipse.preferences.main  (bundle: com.android.ide.eclipse.base, page:   
  com.android.ide.eclipse.common.preferences.UsagePreferencePage)
```

and I can't find the Android plugin configuration view in Preferences. I have tried starting eclipse with the `-clean` option  and running eclipse as administrator but the problem remains.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you as a beginner, please download ADT bundle for windows from:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#win-bundle

**As the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) says:**

```
With a single download, the ADT Bundle includes everything you need to begin developing apps:

Eclipse + ADT plugin
Android SDK Tools
Android Platform-tools
The latest Android platform
The latest Android system image for the emulator
```